# JavaFX Spinner keeps spinning after Alert

Tags: javafx

I have an interesting issue concerning JavaFX spinners (javafx.scene.control.Spinner)...

For my Spinner, I would like to display a "warning" alert when the user first clicks on either the increment or decrement button. The trouble is that the alert displays just fine but, as soon as it is displayed, the spinner continues to increment/decrement on its own. It continues to "spin" forever.

Here is how I am implementing my spinner, with the following abstract class...

```
public abstract class TimeSpinner extends Spinner<LocalTime> {
    protected abstract void displayPopUpOrNot();
    
    @Override
    public void decrement(int steps) {
        displayPopUpOrNot();
        try {
            getValueFactory().setValue(LocalTime.parse(getEditor().getText(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(UtilitiesBean.FORMAT_TIMEONLY_12HR, Locale.ENGLISH)));
            super.decrement(steps);
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            getEditor().setText(UtilitiesBean.INSTANCE.formatLocalTime(LocalTime.now(), UtilitiesBean.FORMAT_TIMEONLY_12HR));
            getValueFactory().setValue(LocalTime.now());
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void increment(int steps) {
        displayPopUpOrNot();
        try {
            getValueFactory().setValue(LocalTime.parse(getEditor().getText(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(UtilitiesBean.FORMAT_TIMEONLY_12HR, Locale.ENGLISH)));
            super.increment(steps);
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            getEditor().setText(UtilitiesBean.INSTANCE.formatLocalTime(LocalTime.now(), UtilitiesBean.FORMAT_TIMEONLY_12HR));
            getValueFactory().setValue(LocalTime.now());
        }
    }
    
}
```

...which is then extended by my concrete spinner classes, like so...

```
public class Spinner1 extends TimeSpinner {
    private boolean warningDisplayed = false;

    protected void displayPopUpOrNot() {
        if (!warningDisplayed) {
            warningDisplayed = true;
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, SPINNER_1_MESSAGE);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

}
```

The "displayPopUpOrNot" method contains the code to display the alert. It only executes when the user first clicks on either the increment or decrement spinner buttons since afterwards it sets the warningDisplayed flag to prevent further execution.

My spinner initialization code includes the following...

```
timeSpinner.setValueFactory(new TimeSpinnerValueFactory());
```

...and my TimeSpinnerValueFactory is defined as follows...

```
public class TimeSpinnerValueFactory extends SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime> {
    {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(UtilitiesBean.FORMAT_TIMEONLY_12HR, Locale.ENGLISH);
        setConverter(new LocalTimeStringConverter(formatter, null));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void decrement(int steps) {
        if (getValue() == null)
            setValue(LocalTime.now());
        else {
            try {
                LocalTime time = getValue();
                setValue(time.minusMinutes(steps));
            }
            catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                setValue(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void increment(int steps) {
        if (this.getValue() == null)
            setValue(LocalTime.now());
        else {
            try {
                LocalTime time = getValue();
                setValue(time.plusMinutes(steps));
            }
            catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                setValue(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Apologies if I have included more code than necessary in this post.

Does anyone know why the spinner continues to spin after the alert is displayed and how to prevent this? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks for any advice!

**Update 2021-01-20:** I have simplified my spinner to be just an Integer spinner. In addition, I have attempted to put the spinner logic in the results function of the Alert, as per Madison's suggestion below (thanks Madison!).

In so doing, I have discovered that the issue appears to be that when the Alert is displayed, the logic behaves as if the user is holding down the increment/decrement button. Calls to the increment/decrement function continue forever.

If it helps, here is my (hopefully minimal) Spinner logic which should show this behaviour...

```
public class IntegerSpinner extends Spinner<Integer> {
    private boolean popupDisplayed = false;
    private boolean popupClosed = false;
    
    @Override
    public void decrement(int steps) {
        System.out.print("Decrement method called. ");
        displayPopUpOrNot(false, steps);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void increment(int steps) {
        System.out.print("Increment method called. ");
        displayPopUpOrNot(true, steps);
    }
    
    private void incrementDecrement(boolean increment, int steps) {
        System.out.print("Popup is now closed. ");
        if (increment) {
            super.increment(steps);
            System.out.println("Increment operation executed.");
        }
        else {
            super.decrement(steps);
            System.out.println("Decrement operation executed");
        }
    }
    
    protected void displayPopUpOrNot(boolean increment, int steps) {
        if (!popupDisplayed) {
            System.out.println("Popup is being prepared for display.");
            popupDisplayed = true;
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, "My spinner message");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();
            if (option.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                popupClosed = true;
                incrementDecrement(increment, steps);
            }
        }
        else if (popupClosed) {
            incrementDecrement(increment, steps);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Popup is open. Increment/decrement operation skipped.");
        }
    }
    
}
```

My code to create the spinner includes the following...

```
IntegerSpinner integerSpinner = new IntegerSpinner();
integerSpinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 600, 300));
```

So here is my follow-up question to this issue - is there a way to "programmatically" turn off the mouse click for a Spinner? Again, the logic is behaving as if the mouse is being held down on the Spinner and I would like to somehow turn this off. Of course, I am open to any other suggestions as to how to solve this issue.

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks again to all who have replied up to this point!

Comment: [mcve] please .. not entirely certain what you are trying to achieve, but on face-value start a Timeline that's hiding the alert after a certain duration ..

Comment: Yes, I was afraid I had included too much code. Again, my apologies. This is my first post to this forum. I am just trying to display an alert when a user clicks the up or down arrow on my spinner, without the spinner continuing on its own. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: This may be better suited for a clock. I haven't tried it. https://github.com/HanSolo/odometer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this issue and I wish to share it in case anyone else runs into this problem.

It turns out that when the alert is displayed in response to clicking the increment or decrement button on the spinner, the mouse-click event is processed but not the mouse-release event. This means that, indeed, as far as the logic in concerned, the mouse is being held down on the increment/decrement button while the alert is being displayed.

In order to prevent the resulting endless spinning, the increment/decrement logic must be skipped until after the alert is closed and the mouse is again clicked on either the increment or decrement button.

To do this, a mouse handler can be added to the spinner which includes the following code...

```
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            if (integerSpinner.isPopupClosed()) {
                integerSpinner.setMouseClickedPostPopup(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

...and the displayPopUpOrNot method in the spinner can be modified as follows...

```
    protected void displayPopUpOrNot(boolean increment, int steps) {
        if (!popupDisplayed) {
            popupDisplayed = true;
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, "My spinner message");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();
            if (option.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                popupClosed = true;
            }
        }
        else if (popupClosed && mouseClickedPostPopup) {
            incrementDecrement(increment, steps);
        }
    }
```

I've implemented this logic in my original application and everything now works fine. Thanks again for the earlier suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider putting the spinner logic in the results function for the alert popup. For example if the user presses OK then spin, else don't spin. This will allow the program to only spin when the user closes the alert.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Madison! I've tried to do this, but still no luck so far. Perhaps I'm not doing it properly, not certain. In any case, please see my Update 2020-01-20 in my original post for more info.